# Is there a short-hand to return an arbitrary exit code from shell

Tags: shell-script, ssh

The commands `true` and `false` do nothing but return `0` and `1` respectively. I am looking for a similar command to do nothing but return an arbitrary exit code for testing purposes.

With that, I could

```
ssh remote return 27; echo $?
```

Which does not work because

```
bash: line 0: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, just as I write out the question, the obvious solution came to my mind but maybe someone else can use it one day:

```
ssh remote exit 27; echo "$?"
```

works as desired...!

Comment: The edit added quotes but I am not sure for what purpose.